# Can Guitar pro 6 read files from a link?

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, guitar-pro

I am wondering if guitar pro 6 can read files from a link, I mean :

- File/Open file
- Copy paste my link where the tab is (IE : http://website.com/my_uber_tabs.gp5)

And bang, guitar pro downloads as TMP file, or in a folder dedicated to its tabs (I don't know, like in C://Users/Me/My Documents/GP6/Tabs), and Yey you can read and play your tab on GP6 !

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want that? Just download the file to your local machine...

Comment: Well, I'll just copy paste a link, and it downloads (or not), and open it. That would be easier than downloading it myself, then search in the containing folder, then open it myself. I want to open tabs from my own "cloud" filesystem through an URL.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how windows reads files, which has nothing to do with music.

Comment: I can't see the offtopic here. I am talking about a music software. You know that VLC a video player, can read from the web through an URL ? And that's not because of an operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been a guitar pro 6 user for years now. You can't load files directly from the web like that, unless there is some hidden feature that allows you to, but not the way you mentioned.

However, what you can do is download your file through the browser and set the browser settings(or your download manager) to automatically open the file once done downloading. This will allow your GP6 to open the file once you get it.

Make sure your GP6 has its file associations working, if not you can do so under File->Restore File Associations

Comment: Well that can be a workarround. Thanks for your answer, I wish that Guitar pro team develops a feature like that, it would be awesome !